# Boolean method to check whether List<DateTime> are sequential at one-hour interval

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to make a method which checks whether an entire `List<DateTime>` contains only sequential at one-hour interval.

An example (working case):

- 1/1/2020 00:00 AM
- 1/1/2020 01:00 AM
- 1/1/2020 02:00 AM

An example (broken case):

- 1/1/2020 00:00 AM
- 1/1/2020 01:00 AM
- 1/1/2020 03:00 AM

and so on.

If there is a DateTime which is not one-hour after the previous, it should return false.

**Edit:**

Something like:

```cs
public static bool IsSequential(List<DateTime> sequence)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count - 1; ++i)
    {
        var expected = sequence[i].AddHours(1);
        var next = sequence[i + 1];
        if (next.Year != expected.Year && next.Month != expected.Month && next.Hour != expected.Hour)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's a list.  Use a for loop initialized at index 1 and check the previous value with each iteration.

Comment: That would be `for (var idx = 1; idx < yourList.Count; ++idx) { if (yourList[idx - 1].AddHours(1.0) != yourList[idx]) { return false; } } return true;`, I guess,

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Added my example to the question.

Comment: @nop in your example you're exclusively checking for year, month and hour. That'd work but instead calculate `TimeSpan` between 2 dates and read `TotalHours` of `TimeSpan` as done [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/chash-program-to-determine-the-difference-in-hours-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this

**Given**

```
// projecting time and index, then using `All`

public static bool CheckSequence(List<DateTime> source) 
    => source.Select((time, i) => (time, i))
             .All(x => x.time == source[0].AddHours(x.i));

// Or if you like for loops

public static bool CheckSequence(List<DateTime> source)
{
   for (var i = 1; i < source.Count; i++)
      if (source[i-1].AddHours(1) != source[i] )
         return false;
   return true;
}

// or a slightly more allocatey approach 

public static bool CheckSequence(List<DateTime> source)
 =>  Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count)
               .Select(x => source[0].AddHours(x))
               .SequenceEqual(source);
```

**Tests**

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var sequence1 = new List<DateTime>(){now.AddHours(1), now.AddHours(2), now.AddHours(3)};
var sequence2 = new List<DateTime>(){now.AddHours(1), now.AddHours(3), now.AddHours(3)};

Console.WriteLine(CheckSequence(sequence1));
Console.WriteLine(CheckSequence(sequence2));
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UlBKc1)

---

Comment from [@Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9340890/dave)

> if all dates are at one hour interval, but not in the order, it needs to be ordered first `.OrderBy(x => x)`

That's to say, if you need to do this with an unordered list

```
public static bool CheckSequence(List<DateTime> source) 
    => source.OrderBy(x => x)
             .Select((time, i) => (time, i))
             .All(x => x.time == source[0].AddHours(x.i));
```

---

**Additional Resouces**

- [`Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating
> the element's index.

- [`Enumerable.All<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

- [`DateTime.AddHours(Double)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours?view=net-5.0)

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of hours to the
> value of this instance.

- [`Enumerable.Range(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-5.0)

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

- [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether two sequences are equal according to an equality
> comparer.

Comment: nice solution, i didn't think of this way. just expanding if someone needs it, if all dates are at one hour interval, but not in the order, it needs to be ordered first `.OrderBy(x => x)`

Comment: I really like the way that @TheGeneral has put this answer together. And the solution is pretty good, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the massively underappreciated `System.Interactive` package*, you'll gain a `Scan(seed, (ac, v) => ac)` extension method on `IEnumerable`, which lets you do this:

```cs
var nums = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
            
var isGood = nums
    .Scan((diff: 1, prev: 0), 
          (ac, x) => (diff: x - ac.prev, prev: x))
    .All(t => t.diff == 1);
```

* offering all the extended functional goodies of Rx, but for enumerables: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/

---

And to do it with dates:

```cs
var isGood = dates
    .Scan((diff: default(TimeSpan), prev: default(DateTime)), 
          (ac, x) => (diff: x - ac.prev, prev: x))
    .Skip(1)
    .All(t => t.diff == TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

The `.Skip(1)` is needed to ignore the first diff in the sequence, which will be between the default(DateTime) and the first element

Comment: Kudos for suggesting the rarely mentioned [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package. Btw the [Scan](https://morelinq.github.io/2.6/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Scan.htm) operator is also available in the [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library.

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there, I only would make it more generic, and create an extension method for it, so you can use it as a LINQ method.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

### Short solution: solves only this problem

You have a sequence of DateTimes, and you want to know if the "Distance" between all consecutive DateTimes is excactly one hour

```
public static bool IsAllOneHourDistance(this IEnumerable<DateTime> dateTimes)
{
    // TODO: exception if dateTimes == null
    IEnumerator<DateTime> enumerator = dateTimes.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        TimeSpan oneHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

        // there is at least one DateTime in the sequence
        bool allOneHourDistance = true;
        DateTime previousDateTime = dateTime.Current;

        // enumerate the rest:
        while (allOneHourDistance && enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
             // there is a next DateTime:
             Datetime nextDateTime = enumerator.Current;
             allOneHourDistance = nextDateTime - previousDateTime == oneHour;
             previousDateTime = nextDateTime;
        }
        return allOneHourDistance;
    }
    else
    {
         // empty sequence. TODO: decide whether this returns true of false;
    }
}
```

This stops as soon as you found an incorrect distance, or when you've enumerated the complete sequence. It also works with empty sequence and sequence with one item.

Usage:

```
Datetime today = DateTime.Today;
IEnumerable<DateTime> todaysProcessCompleteTimes = this.Processes
    .Where(process => process.StartTime.Date == today)
    .Select(process => process.EndTime);
bool allOneHourDistance = todaysProcessCompleteTimes.IsAllOneHourDistance();
```

If you want, you can do this using LINQ. you can ZIP the sequence with itself (1), Select the "distance" and check if all Distances have the same Distance.

```
// TODO: make an extension method
TimeSpan oneHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateTimes = ...
bool allOneHourDistance = dateTimes.Zip(dateTimes.Skip(1),
    (first, second) => second - first)
    .All(distance => distance == oneHour);
```

Stops as soon as one false is met. Returns true if less than two elements.

### Reusable solution: generic extension method

So you have an enumerable sequence of similar items. Every item in this sequence has a property of some type. This type has the notion of "Distance". You want to know if every item in the sequence has the same Distance.

```
public bool HasDesiredDistance<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, bool> hasDesiredDistance)
{
    return source.Zip(source.Skip(1),
    (first, second) => hasDesiredDistance(first, second))
    .All(x=> x);
}
```

Or if you want to tell which properties to use and which value:

```
public bool HasDesiredDistance<TSource, TProperty>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TProperty> propertySelector,
    TProperty desiredValue)
{
    return source.Zip(source.Skip(1),
        (first, second) => propertySelector(first) - propertySelector(second))
        .All(distance => distance ==  desiredValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
TimeSpan oneHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
IEnumerable<Process> processes = ...
bool todaysProcessEveryHour = this.Processes
    .Where(process => process.StartTime.Date == today)
    .HasDesiredDistance(process => process.EndTime, oneHour);
```

Comment: The `Zip` operator is not suitable for zipping unknown enumerables with themselves, because it will cause them to be enumerated twice. Which can be problematic with deferred enumerables that hit the filesystem or the database each time they are enumerated. The `Zip` operator is OK only with materialized collections, like arrays and `List`s. You could fix this by changing the argument in the method signatures from `this IEnumerable` to `this ICollection`. An `ICollection` could still be deferred theoretically, but in practice it never is.

Comment: There is no database involved; the question clearly states that the data is In a List. But even if the data is in an IQueryable:  use my first solution, which will access every element only once.

Comment: Harald I am not sure I understand. You generalized beyond the OP's specific problem that involves `List`s, by offering reusable generic extension methods that are not actually reusable. Why?